# AJAX validation on simple form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am trying to do client-side validation using AJAX to check for empty fields on a simple form. If the field is empty, I want to notify the user that this is not valid. The form should not submit if there are any empty fields.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Ajax is not required for client-side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is not required to do client-side validation.  I can only assumed you're interchanging the term with "jQuery".  In that case...

[jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) is, by far, the mostly widely used jQuery validation plugin.

> "The plugin is written and maintained by Jörn Zaefferer, a member of
>   the jQuery team, lead developer on the jQuery UI team and maintainer
>   of QUnit. It was started back in the early days of jQuery in 2006, and
>   updated and improved since then."

Here is a working demo...

**http://jsfiddle.net/EggSb/**

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                // other rules
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                // other rules
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">  
     <input type="text" name="field1" />
     <input type="text" name="field2" />
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this will help. I know AJAX is not required but I wanted to notify the user as soon as they left the field empty (onchange) rather than at the end when they hit the "submit" button. 
I'm probably confusing what to use.

Comment: @user2048889, this plugin already has that default behavior... [just try the demo in my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/EggSb/).  It validates each field `onkeyup` and `onblur`, but those options can be disabled.  Play around with it and post a new question when you get stuck.

Comment: the demo was very helpful; I played around with it and got it working perfectly to fit my needs! What I would like to ask you now is how to integrate this into a website using XAMPP (if you happen to know). I noticed it shows what parts are HTML, CSS, and JScript...do I just add those onto my code?

Comment: @user2048889, That's a whole new SO question you should post.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use AJAX if all you are testing for is empty fields. If you are targeting browsers that support HTML5 forms you can just do:

```
<input type="text" name="username" required />
```

If you are required to support other browsers like IE you will need to use JavaScript. Google "JavaScript form validation library" to find examples of JavaScript to do this.